# ESP32 FreeRTOS deleting a task from another task

Tags: c++, class, static-methods, esp32, freertos

I am learning FreeRTOS and stumbled accross this issue and cannot fully understand what is the problem. I am trying to switch between freertos tasks from within a static method but it hangs on vtaskdelete.
The main class method that I have is the state_change_handle. It ensures that only 1 freertos task runs at the time and when I switch between task1 and task2, it deletes the currently running task and starts a new one.

My controller.cpp:

```
#include "Controller.h"

Controller::Controller(){
    printf("Thermostat object created \n");
}

void Controller::begin(){
    this->test1 = 0;
    this->old_state = INITIAL;
    this->main_task_handle = NULL;
    printf("Start the task1 \n");
    this->State_change_handle(TASK2);
}

void Controller::State_change_handle(e_thermostat_state state)
{
    this-> new_state = state;
    if(this-> old_state != this-> new_state ){ // if the new state is different than current state, delete the task
        printf("different state, delete the previous task \n");
        if (this ->main_task_handle != NULL){
            vTaskDelete(this ->main_task_handle);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("same task \n"); // the same task is set, dont do anything
        return;
    }
        
    switch(this->new_state) 
    {   
        case TASK1:
            printf("NEW STATE = MODE1 \n");
            this-> old_state = TASK1;
            xTaskCreate(task1,"MODE1",10000,this,1,&this->main_task_handle); // receiving commands from main uart
            break;

        case TASK2:
            printf("NEW STATE = MODE2\n");
            this-> old_state = TASK2;
            xTaskCreate(task2,"MODE2",10000,this,1,&this->main_task_handle); // receiving commands from main uart
            break;

        default:
            printf("state not recognised \n");
    }
}
```

Controller.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include "stdint.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"



enum e_thermostat_state
{
    INITIAL,
    TASK1,
    TASK2,
    TASK3,
    MAX_STATES
};


class Controller
{
    private://only accesible for class
        int test1;
        e_thermostat_state new_state;
        e_thermostat_state old_state;
        TaskHandle_t main_task_handle;
        TaskHandle_t secondary_task_handle;
        

    public: 
    //accesible outside class
        Controller();                                                   // INIT OBJECT
        void begin();
        void State_change_handle(e_thermostat_state state);


        static void task1(void* parameters)
        {
            Controller* controller = (Controller*)parameters;         
            for(;;)
            {   
                printf("test 1 =%i\n",controller->test1);
                printf("hello from task 1\n");
                vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_RATE_MS);
            }
        }


        static void task2(void* parameters)
        {
            
            Controller* controller = (Controller*)parameters;
            for(;;)
            {   
                printf("hello from task 2\n");
                controller->test1 ++;
                printf("test 1 inside task2 = %i \n",controller->test1);
                vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_RATE_MS);
                if(controller->test1 >= 10){
                    controller->test1 = 0;
                    controller->State_change_handle(TASK1);
                }
            }
        }



        
        //static void normal_operation_task(void *argument);                                 // DECLARE DEFAULT THERMOSTAT STATES AND VARS       
};




#endif
```

In my main.c I create class object and call begin method. Inside begin method, state_change_handle(TASK2) is called and task2 is started. Once the counter value reaches 10, I want to delete task2 and start task1, however, my program freezes when vtaskdelete is called

```
vTaskDelete(this ->main_task_handle);
```

Serial monitor:

```
Start the task1
different state, delete the previous task
PROGRAM STUCK
NEW STATE = MODE2
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 1
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 2 
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 3 
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 4 
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 5 
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 6
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 7
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 8
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 9
hello from task 2
test 1 inside task2 = 10
different state, delete the previous task
```

I have tried adding an additional print statement after vTaskDelete but it did not print.

I run this program on ESP32 development board, you can download my code:
https://github.com/krupis/ESP32

Please could someone help me find a problem?

```
Controller* controller = (Controller*)parameters;
```

Could there be some issues with the way I create this pointer to the controller object and then use it to call class method?

Comment: Is the Serial Monitor giving you a stack trace? If there's some sort of illegal access you should get a long set of memory addresses that map to your code. Your use of controller via parameters isn't the issue or you wouldn't get to the delete part of your code

Comment: I think I have managed to solve the issue. The issue was due to me calling a method that deletes the task itself. Since the task gets deleted, nothing else is happing and the task hangs. The correct way to handle this situation is make sure the new task is created before the old one is deleted and not vice versa.

Comment: That makes sense, you should also consider FreeRTOS communication primitives for something like this. You could have a task in charge of managing your other tasks and gets messages on which task to start

Comment: Yes I have been considering this sort of idea for a while now. I am trying to find some information to read about how to actually do it ( whether I should be using queues or something else). Perhaps you know where I can find some good information about that?